# 90s YA vampire romance short novel where a girl moves to a new town and invites a vampire into her house

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, vampire, novella

I'm struggling to get the title of a young-adult vampire horror/romance short novel that was written in the 90s about a teenage girl named Christina (I believe) who moves to a new creepy town where she meets a vampire and invites him into her home. Unfortunately, I don't remember any clear details because I read the book over 10 years ago. However, one line from the book has always stuck with me - she apparently had a large bust for her age [~17], but was very thin, and one of her friends tells her that if her breasts grow any more she'll fall over/have trouble getting around.

Comment: Honorable mention of *[Vampires Promise #2 - Evil Returns](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/794005.Evil_Returns)*, which has Devnee moving into a new home, and finding the vampire living there, who grants her beauty in exchange for her helping feed another girl to him.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's *[The Silver Kiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silver_Kiss)* (1990) by Annette Curtis Klause. Her protagonist's name is Zoë. Here's the scene:

> “Bull,” Zoë said. “You’ve got a great figure, not like me.
>
> Lorraine sniffed. “You might be skinny, but your bra’s bigger than mine. You better eat more, otherwise every time you get up, you’ll fall over from the weight of your tits.”

And her best friend, Lorraine moves to Oregon.